Is there any way or packages that can help me plot logarithmic graphs in flutter?
I am trying to plot a logarithmic (semilog) graph using a set of data coming from a flask backend. Most of the flutter packages support normal line charts only. Is there any way to achieve this? Can the line chart be modified to create one?
I have tried fl_chart for cases where only normal line charts was needed. But couldn't create semilog graphs using it

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
